# How to write a Column of a Datatable to XML with few tweaks?

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, datatable, playlist

I have a on memory Datatable like this.

[image: datatable]

I want to produce xml file like this.

[image: xml]

The URL (e.g. http:\www.mymusicwebsite.com\songs) will always be the same.
Could anyone teach me how do I achieve this ?

Thanks A Lot.

L

Comment: In which format you can access this data table? Is `DataTable` class or what?

Comment: The songs details are in the database but the DataTable is produced dynamically when user clicks choose to see the songs that they filtered (e.g. using checkboxlists/dropdownlist). Thanks.

Comment: the DataTable is also binded to a gridview as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using LINQ-to-XML:

```
// test items set, you need change to the column accessor
// like dataTable.Rows[2] or dataTable.Rows["fileName"]
// or row.Field<string>("filename") as noted by Mentoliptus
IList<string> items = new List<string> { "song1.mp3", "song2.mp3", "song3.mp3" };

XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
xws.Indent = true;

// You can output to file or even in a string
using (var stream = File.Create(@"C:\test.xml"))
using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, xws))
{                
    var xml = new XElement("smil",
        new XElement("body",
            new XElement("seq",
                items.Select(c => new XElement("media", 
                                   new XAttribute(
                                       "src",
                                       String.Format("http:\\\\www..mysite.com\\songs\\{0}", c)))))));

    xml.Save(xw);
}
```

**Output:**

```xml
<smil>
  <body>
    <seq>
      <media src="http:\\www..mysite.com\songs\song1.mp3" />
      <media src="http:\\www..mysite.com\songs\song2.mp3" />
      <media src="http:\\www..mysite.com\songs\song3.mp3" />
    </seq>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Comment: Thanks sll, it works well ... Magic!
but I found out Linq in C# is abit different to vb.net. Can't just use an online converter to get vb.net code. Don't worry I will figure this out. Thanks.

Comment: Happy to know, thanks for eltting me know. LINQ really is great feature!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use LINQ to XML, like this:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = new XDocument(
   new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
      new XElement("smil",
         new XElement("body",
            new XElement("seq",
               from row in SongsDataTable.AsEnumerable()
               select new XElement("media", 
                  new XAttribute("src", "http://www.mymusicwebsite.com/songs/" + row.Field<string>("filename")
            )
         )
      )
   )
);
```

Comment: No problem, @sill responded a few minutes before I submitted my answer.